# Panel Data- FE vs RE

Tags: panel-data, stata, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to understand the different Panel Data models and I am getting confused by the different terms that people use, i.e., Random effect ***models*** and Random effects ***estimators*** and Fixed effect *models* and Fixed effect *estimators*- are these 4 all different?

Is it the case that you can have a *fixed* effect *estimator* in a *random* effects *model* and if you do that your estimate is not consistent?

For context, I am running a panel data analysis in STATA and after conducting a Hausman Test my p-value is more that 0.05 indicating I should use a random effects model. Does this mean I simply use the ,re output as my result or does it mean there's something in my variables and controls that needs to be changed or considered?

I am running a regression of total inflow **migration** on **gov spending on healthcare** per capita. My other x variables are population density, share of elderly, total tax revenue, GDP per capita and gini.

I understand that I am not to include variables that do not vary over time within a country- or is that only for fixed effects? So I'm not sure if my x variables are '*correct*'

I'm sorry these are quite a few questions but any help at all would be *GREATLY* appreciated. The more that I try to read about panel data models, the more I get myself confused so if someone could explain for my specific case that would be amazing. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

*RE model:* panel data model with some restrictions on the individual effects (such as being uncorrelated with the regressors for linear panel data models).

*FE model:* panel data model without such restrictions (so the individual effects can be correlated with the regressors).

*FE estimator:* A particular estimator, also known as 'within-group' estimator, usually for linear panel data models with strictly exogenous regressors; can be computed by Stata's `xtreg, fe`.

*RE estimator:* A particular FGLS estimator for the linear error component model (the error term = individual effects ($u_i$) + idiosyncratic error ($e_{it}$), where $u_i$ and $e_{it}$ are mutually uncorrelated, $e_{it}$ are homoskedastic and serially uncorrelated); can be computed by Stata's `xtreg, re`.

FE estimator is consistent for both FE and RE models. RE estimator is consistent for RE models but inconsistent for FE models in general.